# Combobox value hiding when add New record in datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net

[image]
Hiding previous row value

Previous combobox data is hiding in datagridview when enter new row in datagridview using vb.net, and I want to know how to do cascading combox in datagridview combobox

```
Private Sub dgsalorder_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)Handles dgsalorder.CellEnter


If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then

        Dim i As Integer = dgsalorder.CurrentRow.Index

        Dim styleval = dgsalorder.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
      If Convert.ToBoolean(dgsalorder.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value) = True Then
                If styleval > 0 Then
                    Dim mysqlda As New SqlDataAdapter
                    Dim mysqldt As New DataTable

                    mysqlda = New SqlDataAdapter("select id,BrandID,ColorID,PackID,SizeMasterID,Pairpercarton,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12,s13,s14,s15,s16,s17,s18,s19,s20,s21,s22,s23,s24,s25,s26,s27,s28,s29,s30 from StyleMaster where Id='" & styleval.ToString & "'", con)
                    mysqlda.Fill(mysqldt)
                    If mysqldt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                        brand = mysqldt.Rows(0)(1).ToString()
                        color = mysqldt.Rows(0)(2).ToString()
                        Pack = mysqldt.Rows(0)(3).ToString()
                        Size = mysqldt.Rows(0)(4).ToString()
                        totalqty = mysqldt.Rows(0)(5).ToString()
                     Dim strQuery As String = "select id,BrandName from BrandMaster where id='" + brand.ToString + "'"
                        lblbrands.DisplayMember = "_Value"
                        lblbrands.ValueMember = "_Key"
                        lblbrands.DataSource = getcombobox(strQuery)



                        Colorcolumn = DirectCast(dgsalorder.Columns("lblcolors"), System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
                        Dim strQuery1 As String = "select id,ColorCode from ColorMaster where id='" + color.ToString + "'"
                        Colorcolumn.DisplayMember = "_Value"
                        Colorcolumn.ValueMember = "_Key"
                        Colorcolumn.DataSource = getcombobox(strQuery1)

 end sub
```

Comment: Why do you have an event handler that is named for the CellValueChanged event but handling the CellEnter event? That's a red flag right off the bat.

Comment: You are changing the DataSource for the whole column so of course you're affecting other cells. Without testing myself, I would think that you should leave the column and cells bound to the full list and do the filtering in the editing control only. That would mean handling the EditingControlShowing event and binding the editing control directly.

Comment: Can you give Example for cascading comobobox in datagridview vb.net

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of filtering a second combo box column based on the selection in the first combo box column in the same row. The column is bound to the full list of possible values, so any value in every cell is valid. When editing a cell, the editing control is bound to a partial list that is filtered appropriately.

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Private ReadOnly data As New DataSet
    Private ReadOnly categoryTable As DataTable = data.Tables.Add("Category")
    Private ReadOnly subcategoryTable As DataTable = data.Tables.Add("Subcategory")
    Private ReadOnly mainTable As DataTable = data.Tables.Add("Main")

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        With categoryTable.Columns
            .Add("CategoryId", GetType(Integer))
            .Add("Name", GetType(String))
        End With

        With categoryTable.Rows
            .Add(1, "Category 1")
            .Add(2, "Category 2")
            .Add(3, "Category 3")
        End With

        With subcategoryTable.Columns
            .Add("SubcategoryId", GetType(Integer))
            .Add("CategoryId", GetType(Integer))
            .Add("Name", GetType(String))
        End With

        With subcategoryTable.Rows
            .Add(1, 1, "Subcategory 1A")
            .Add(2, 1, "Subcategory 1B")
            .Add(3, 1, "Subcategory 1C")
            .Add(4, 2, "Subcategory 2A")
            .Add(5, 2, "Subcategory 2B")
            .Add(6, 2, "Subcategory 2C")
            .Add(7, 3, "Subcategory 3A")
            .Add(8, 3, "Subcategory 3B")
            .Add(9, 3, "Subcategory 3C")
        End With

        With mainTable.Columns
            .Add("MainId", GetType(Integer)).AutoIncrement = True
            .Add("CategoryId", GetType(Integer))
            .Add("SubcategoryId", GetType(Integer))
        End With

        With mainTable.Rows
            .Add(Nothing, 1, 1)
            .Add(Nothing, 2, 5)
            .Add(Nothing, 3, 9)
        End With

        categoryBindingSource.DataSource = categoryTable
        subcategoryBindingSource.DataSource = subcategoryTable
        filteredSubcategoryBindingSource.DataSource = New DataView(subcategoryTable)
        mainBindingSource.DataSource = mainTable

        With categoryColumn
            .ValueMember = "CategoryId"
            .DisplayMember = "Name"
            .DataSource = categoryBindingSource
        End With

        'The subcategory column is bound to the full list of subcategories, so any value in any cell will be valid.
        With subcategoryColumn
            .ValueMember = "SubcategoryId"
            .DisplayMember = "Name"
            .DataSource = subcategoryBindingSource
        End With

        DataGridView1.DataSource = mainBindingSource
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
        If e.ColumnIndex = 1 AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
            'When a category changes, clear the subcategory in the same row as the current value cannot be valid.
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value = DBNull.Value
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
        Dim currentCellAddress = DataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress

        If currentCellAddress.X = 2 Then
            'When selecting a subcategory, bind the editing control to a partial list filtered by the category selected in the same row.
            Dim currentRow = DirectCast(mainBindingSource.Current, DataRowView).Row
            Dim categoryId = currentRow.Field(Of Integer)("CategoryId")
            Dim subcategoryId = If(currentRow.Field(Of Integer?)("SubcategoryId"), DBNull.Value)

            filteredSubcategoryBindingSource.Filter = $"CategoryId = {categoryId}"

            With DirectCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
                .ValueMember = "SubcategoryId"
                .DisplayMember = "Name"
                .DataSource = filteredSubcategoryBindingSource
                .SelectedValue = subcategoryId
            End With
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

This relies on an appropriately configured `DataGridView` and `BindingSources`. Here is the designer code I used:

```vb
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
        Me.mainBindingSource = New System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(Me.components)
        Me.categoryBindingSource = New System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(Me.components)
        Me.DataGridView1 = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView()
        Me.subcategoryBindingSource = New System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(Me.components)
        Me.filteredSubcategoryBindingSource = New System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(Me.components)
        Me.idColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        Me.categoryColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
        Me.subcategoryColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
        CType(Me.mainBindingSource, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.categoryBindingSource, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.DataGridView1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.subcategoryBindingSource, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.filteredSubcategoryBindingSource, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'DataGridView1
        '
        Me.DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize
        Me.DataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn() {Me.idColumn, Me.categoryColumn, Me.subcategoryColumn})
        Me.DataGridView1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 12)
        Me.DataGridView1.Name = "DataGridView1"
        Me.DataGridView1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(506, 426)
        Me.DataGridView1.TabIndex = 0
        '
        'idColumn
        '
        Me.idColumn.DataPropertyName = "MainId"
        Me.idColumn.HeaderText = "ID"
        Me.idColumn.Name = "idColumn"
        Me.idColumn.ReadOnly = True
        '
        'categoryColumn
        '
        Me.categoryColumn.DataPropertyName = "CategoryId"
        Me.categoryColumn.HeaderText = "Category"
        Me.categoryColumn.Name = "categoryColumn"
        '
        'subcategoryColumn
        '
        Me.subcategoryColumn.DataPropertyName = "SubcategoryId"
        Me.subcategoryColumn.HeaderText = "Subcategory"
        Me.subcategoryColumn.Name = "subcategoryColumn"
        Me.subcategoryColumn.Width = 120
        '
        'Form1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(800, 450)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.DataGridView1)
        Me.Name = "Form1"
        Me.Text = "Form1"
        CType(Me.mainBindingSource, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        CType(Me.categoryBindingSource, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        CType(Me.DataGridView1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        CType(Me.subcategoryBindingSource, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        CType(Me.filteredSubcategoryBindingSource, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub

    Friend WithEvents mainBindingSource As BindingSource
    Friend WithEvents categoryBindingSource As BindingSource
    Friend WithEvents DataGridView1 As DataGridView
    Friend WithEvents subcategoryBindingSource As BindingSource
    Friend WithEvents filteredSubcategoryBindingSource As BindingSource
    Friend WithEvents idColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents categoryColumn As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents subcategoryColumn As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
End Class
```